# Roslyn: how to get type dependencies from a method's body with no source code

Tags: c#, reflection, roslyn

I want to collect all types used/referenced from within an assembly using Roslyn. This works fine for all type usages, except for the types used in local variable declarations.

Without Roslyn I would use the LocalVariable property of a MethodBody object of the C# reflection API.

My question is how to do this with Roslyn?

Comment: Roslyn only operates on source code; it does not have a decompiler.  You want ILSpy.

Comment: Not all types used in a method body have to have a related local variable.

Comment: @thehennyy fair point. Any suggestions about how to deal with this, or is this simply not possible without decompiling?

Comment: Fortunately the .Net framework brings everything you need to decode a method body. Have a look at this `MethodBodyReader` implementation: https://github.com/jbevain/mono.reflection/blob/master/Mono.Reflection/MethodBodyReader.cs.